# How to give permission to specific users to download a Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a google cloud storage bucket with two objects in the bucket. I want to give permission to specific email address so that they can download the bucket content. However, when I try to add principles with "**Storage Legacy Bucket Reader**", I get the below error.

[image]

I have these below configurations in my bucket.

[image]

How can I give read/download access to specific email users without making the bucket public to all users?

Comment: The first message is telling you what the issue is. There is a policy that don't allow external users to be added. You need to check with your org admin. This can be helpful https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-domains